# DateTime removes trailing zeros from milliseconds

Tags: c#, datetime

My Logger class uses DateTime to print up to millisecond accuracy to logfile, however I notice it keeps removing the training zeros which is rather annoying.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
w.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFF") + " [" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "]" + " [INFO] " + logMessage);

2016-03-25 20:25:14.692 [8] [INFO] OUTGOING MESSAGE : test
2016-03-25 20:25:18.1 [8] [INFO] OUTGOING MESSAGE : test
2016-03-25 20:25:18.121 [11] [INFO] INCOMING MESSAGE : testReply
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.fff`. Case matters. I refer you to the excellent documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was completely overlooking the formatting string.

Answer (score 2):

From [The `FFF` Custom Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#FFF_Specifier);

> The "FFF" custom format specifier represents the three most
>   significant digits of the seconds fraction; that is, it represents the
>   milliseconds in a date and time value. **However, trailing zeros or
>   three zero digits are not displayed.**

You can use lower case [`fff` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fffSpecifier) instead.